# Grounding An Electrical Receptacle Inside Enclosure

Tags: grounding

My company ordered several power cabinets to use mains power from a generator to power some DC equipment on a truck.  We also requested a NEMA 5-15 duplex receptacle on the front for ancillary loads.  There are two AC inputs (AC 1 and AC 2) to allow the system to be powered from two independent 100-264V circuits (they are separate AC systems that are paralleled at the DC output).  The receptacle is wired to a separate board that disconnects it when the input rises above 120V.

My understanding of the applicable codes/standards here is hazy at best but I believe NFPA code requires a jumper from the door to the body of the enclosure instead of an implied ground connection through the piano hinge.  Also, I am not sure if the receptacle's ground terminal needs to be connected with its own wire if the metal body is connected directly to a bare metal panel.  Is this wiring setup correct or do we need to go back to the manufacturer for revisions?

[image: electrical receptacle inside enclosure]

Comment: Article 551 may provide some guidance, although it is explicitly for RVs.

Comment: And 250.34 Portable, Vehicle-Mounted, and Trailer-Mounted Generators - (B)(3) has 'The normally non-current-carrying metal parts of equipment and the equipment grounding conductor terminals of the receptacles are connected to the generator frame (which is bonded to the vehicle). So, yes, I'd have a separate bonding to ensure the door is grounded.

Comment: Are the cabinets UL Listed?  I don't see UL approving that on two fronts: First receptacle on the door when it could as easily be on the side of the cabinet.  Second, wires must be bundled to prevent damage, which means you can't have a single flexure point right there at the hinge.  You must have the wires travel vertically along the hinge 8-12 inches, in wire loom e.g. the white twisty stuff, fastened on the door at the bottom and the enclosure at the top. That way all the twisting is axial down the 8-12" free length of the bundle, not *bending* at the hinge.